# read value editbox in ssjs in a custom control

Tags: xpages, custom-controls, xpages-ssjs

I have a custom control with an editbox in a modal:

`<xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>`

In the onclick event of a button , I would like to read the value of this editbox

```
var demo = getComponent("inputText1").getValue();
```

Of course this doesn't work in a custom control, since he doesn't has a handle to inputText1. How can this be done ?

**EDIT**

Herewith I'm posting my 'whole' code.
Even with a scoped variable it isn't working .... :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet href="bootstrap-modal.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:script src="/bootstrap-modalmanager.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    <xp:script src="/bootstrap-modal.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    <xp:script src="/JQueryXSnippet.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>

<div id="Modal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">

<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal One</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<p>Modal 1 </p>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputText1">First Name:</label>
        <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{viewScope.input1}">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="class" value="form-control"></xp:attr>
                <xp:attr name="data-tabindex" value="1"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
        </xp:inputText>
</div> 

<xp:button value="Demo" id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="demoPanel">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.message = "input1 = "+viewScope.input1;}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

<xp:panel id="demoPanel">
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
        value="#{viewScope.message}">
    </xp:text>
</xp:panel>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
</div>
</div>

<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
x$("#{id:button1}").click(function(){
x$("#{id:Modal1}").modal(
{backdrop: true,
keyboard: false,
show: true
}
);
});
});
]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

<xp:button value="Login" id="button1" styleClass="btn btn-info btn-lg">
</xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

The advice from Tim Tripcony was to go to the model layer, not the component. As ever, he was spot on. Bind the Edit Box to something, probably in this scenario a viewScope variable. Then retrieve the value from that. It's likely to be more efficient than `getComponent()`.

Comment: I second what Paul says and use this all the time with modals

Comment: Paul and Chris, have a look at my above code. It seems it doesn't work even with a viewScope variable.

Comment: Please confirm the partial refresh is completing through **all** phases. Add a print statement in as well or, better practice, ensure a "Display Errors" control is in the refresh area. At the moment it's not certain there's an error in your code or some validator / converter error.

Comment: I added a display errors control , but don't get an error. I added a counter in the demoPanel to check if it refreshes and it does. I"ve put a default value for inputText1 which is always displayed as value for the computed field in the demoPanel whatever value I put in the inputText1 box.

Comment: The counter just confirms the partial refresh runs. It doesn't confirm it runs through the phase that runs your SSJS. And for the viewScope variable to be updated, your SSJS needs to run.

Comment: Paul, I've put the increasement in my ssjs to be sure it runs. Meanwhile I gave up the idea to use the bootstrap modal and instead I use the extension library dialog with the exact same code and everything works fine ....

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that spring to mind are worth trying:

1. Add the button to the custom control and that way, it'll just work as is.
2. Set the id to be computed from a custom property of the control `control-id` and pass in a string e.g. `my-made-up-id` and then refer to it from any button out-with the custom control.  Note the `${}` binding is needed when computing the id.

Custom Control

```
<xp:inputText
        id="${javascript:compositeData.control-id}">
    </xp:inputText>
```

XPage

```
<xc:FieldTest control-id="my-made-up-id"></xc:FieldTest>

    <xp:button
        value="Get Value"
        id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var demo = getComponent("my-made-up-id").getValue();
print("Demo: " + demo);}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```